# Laptop charger (USB-C) kaputt, repair, substitute or buy new?

Tags: battery-charging, charger, usb-c, laptop

My laptop charging cable has a presumablyl slack joint and doesn't charge anymore. (It previously charged when you maneuvered the cable into a certain direction).

I'm now contemplating these three options:

a) replace the cable myself, I do own a soldering iron, if it's really just a loose connection I deem myself capable of repairing it. I do assume, that there will be at most three wires inside the cable.

b) Use another usb-charger instead. My current faulty charger is a Lenovo AC Adapter with the following specs:
Output: 20V⎓3.25A / 15V⎓3A / 9V⎓2A / 5V⎓2A

The substitute I planned on using has
Output: 5V⎓3A / 9V⎓3A / 12⎓2.25A / 20V⎓1.35A / 11V⎓3A

Does this work or do I have a realistic chance of damaging the battery? I'm aware that it will probably only charge slower, but that doesn't matter.

c)
Just buy a new charging device. Since I only really need the charger for the next two weeks, I'm not really inclined to take this option, but if that's what it takes, it's what it is.

Comment: Can you repair by shortening the cable, or do you need to rewire the USB connector?

Comment: A lot of laptops are picky about requiring 20V or 15V or whatever and won't charge off 5V. Aside from that, it's usually fine to use a lower amperage charger although I've seen devices switch over to battery and need to be plugged/unplugged. You'll almost never damage a device by plugging in a good charger even if it's incompatible. The worst that happens is the device fails to charge. Dangerous low cost chargers can cause damage though.

Comment: Infinitezero, One more thought. I've experienced cases where the observation is that the cable had to be tensioned in some direction to get charging to take place and that it eventually just stopped working, where it wasn't the charging cable but instead the connector's solder joints lifting from the PC board inside the unit. In those cases, the manufacturer failed to properly solder the physical tabs leaving stresses entirely on the much smaller connection pins. Soldering repaired the problem. Not saying you are wrong. Just keep in mind that certain symptoms may have multiple explanations.

Comment: I'd choose b), a) can be tricky beacuse once I had the same issue but still I don't know why I couldnt melt the tin of the pcb, like it wasn't a normal electronic soldering. So probably you will lose lot of time

Comment: You have no chance of damaging the battery. The device you're talking about is not a charger, just a power supply - the charging circuits are built into the laptop itself. It'll either charge safely or not at all. And given that everything is moving towards USB-C a new purchase is going to be useful for years to come.

Comment: @TEMLIB how would I know that without opening the cable?

Comment: @Finbarr How so? Buying a new laptop charger will likely only be useful for this laptop, which I do not really use, except for 2 weeks occasionally. If I get a new laptop, it will come with a new charger.

Comment: It'll be able to work with pretty much any laptop, phone, tablet or other device that takes power through USB-C.

Comment: So I plugged it in and it's not charging. Looks like @periblepsis is right and it's the connector. Gonna open it tomorrow and take a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the substitute is fine. specs on chargers are supply limits. your replacement is more capable than the original

Comment: The replacement is more capable at 5V and 9V, but not at 20V that the laptop is probably going to need. Still, it should charge but less than half as fast as the original (~27W versus ~65W for the original).

Comment: @StarCat Some laptops may not like not having a 15 V option, too.

Comment: I think the 15V option is on the original